# Error in ntop Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ntop

I am having the following errors, while starting `ntop`, i.e. when I type `sudo ntop`:

```
Error#1:
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  **ERROR** GeoIP: unable to load file GeoLiteCity.dat
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  **ERROR** GeoIP: unable to load ASN file GeoIPASNum.dat
Error#2:
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  INITWEB: Initializing TCP/IP socket connections for web server
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  **ERROR** INITWEB: binding problem - 'Address already in use'(98)
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  Check if another instance of ntop is running
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  or if the current user (-u) can bind to the specified port
Fri Sep  6 09:01:52 2013  **FATAL_ERROR** Binding problem, ntop shutting down...
```

Can anyone please help how to solve this?

Comment: regarding 2nd: run `netstat -plnt` and see if there is another process running.

Answer (score 4):

This is what a top uses to populate the geolocation information of the remote network traffic.

To correct this:

```
wget -N http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
wget -N http://download.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/asnum/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz
gunzip GeoIPASNum.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/GeoIP/
sudo mv GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/
sudo mv GeoIPASNum.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/
```

You may like to update the GeoIP monthly to keep the data up to date.

Source: http://www.mikereamy.com/2013/11/ntop-geoip-error/

Answer (score 0):

This means you are missing GeoIP. This should download, set the directory if not there and "install" it:

```
wget -N http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
sudo mv GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
```

Comment: I am getting error while unziping GeoLiteCity.dat.gz file.          Error is: GeoIPASNum.dat.gz: not in gzip format.                    I am using curl -O instead of wget -N.                              Please help.

Comment: I followed the instructions exactly, and I'm still getting the same error.